# Install SQL Server Express silently

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd, sql-server-express

I am trying to create a `.bat` file to install SQL Server 2014 Express silently, and with my own options, but each time it runs, it quits in the middle.

Here is my command:

```
C:> SQLEXPR_x86_EN /ACTION=Install /QS /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
           /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
           /FEATURES=SQLEngine /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic  
           /INSTANCENAME="MX_SERVER_SQL"  /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1 
           /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
           /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
           /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SECURITYMODE=SQL 
           /SAPWD=My_123456
```

Why does it not run to the end?

ERROR > The installation starts but somewhere after start to load the files it quits and stops the installation and nothing installed

Comment: Well- **what** error are you getting? I'm sure there's **something** being shown - you need to show us! We can't see your computer screen, nor can we read your mind ....

Comment: "Quits in the middle" is excessively vague.  Please describe what happens in more detail.  The more you tell us, the better we can help you.

Comment: @RBarryYoung  it runs little bit and when it starts to load it quits

Comment: Check the windows logs for clues perhaps.

Comment: And what does " when it starts to load" mean?

Comment: Do you need to execute the .bat file within another directory?  I.E. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared

Answer (score 0):

It didn't run to the end because it probably encountered a failure during setup! To diagnose setup failures, look at the [setup log files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.120).aspx).

Specifically, file path `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log`.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sa password i would think it doesn't meet server complexity requirements.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29784418)